# possible concatinate for rails form fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `student` model with fields `:name, :address`.

I want to create 2 different fields `:country, :city`, that, when filled in and submitted, would concatenate into the `address` db field.

How can it be done? Must I define something in `student.rb`? Or just some form view?

my student/_form.haml:

```
= simple_form_for @student do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :country #not in db
  = f.input :city #not in db
  = f.button :submit
```

(address must equal `country + " " + city`)

Note: I do not want to create separate db fields for country & city.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following ways

1. make address in model --> this is the best way
2. make address in controller --> this is good way

***way no 1***
**in model**

```
 attr_accessor :country
 attr_accessor :city

 def before_save
    self.address = @country + " " + @city
 end
```

in controller

```
def save
   student = Student.new()
   student.country = params[:country]
   student.city = params[:city]
   student.save
 end
```

***way no 2*
For example model student, controller Student
in controller**

```
def save
   student = Student.new
   student.address = params[:country] + " " + params[:city]
   student.save
 end
```

I hope it helps.